# R - undo an array_arrange()

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, reshape, reticulate

I am after a way to undo the array_reshape() function in R. Any help is welcomed.

```
library(reticulate) 

mat <- matrix(rep(1:1000), nrow = 10)

mat.1 <- array_reshape(mat, c(nrow(mat), 10,10,1)) 

# make mat.2 the same dimensions as mat
mat.2 <- ???
```

Comment: Please include a call to `library(reticulate)` since `array_reshape` is not a base function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `dim` value of the array like this:

```
dim(mat.1) <- c(10, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just do :

```
mat.2 = mat
```

if you avoid overwriting your first matrix, its still in memory just as before. when you operate on an object in R, R creates a copy automatically, so the operation you did on it was actually made on a copy.

Comment: haha, nice. But I will be doing some stuff to mat.1. Would like to make sure I put it back in the same order as it was. so whatever was in, say,  mat[3,5] gets some stuff done to it while its in mat.1, then gets put back into mat.2[3,5];and so on